# In Html Table is it possible to get the id of elements situated in another row?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have this HTML table structure where I define various rows(tr's):

```
<table>
    <tr><td><button id="1" onclick="getid()"></button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="2" onclick="getid()"></button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="3" onclick="getid()"></button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="4" onclick="getid()"></button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="5" onclick="getid()"></button></td></tr>
</table>
<script>
    function getid(){
        alert($(this).closest('[id]'));
    }
</script>
```

On click of any button I should be able to get the Id of the button situated above row and below row.

Which I am not getting. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify `onclick` handler pass `this` as parameter in the Html and then use `.next()` and `.prev()` jQuery methods as shown below :-

HTML :-

```
<table>
    <tr><td><button id="1" onclick="getid(this)"></button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="2" onclick="getid(this)"></button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="3" onclick="getid(this)"></button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="4" onclick="getid(this)"></button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="5" onclick="getid(this)"></button></td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery :-

```
<script>
function getid(elem){
    alert($(elem).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('button').attr('id'));
    alert($(elem).closest('tr').next('tr').find('button').attr('id'));
}
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wag0zfjd/2/)